# Changing dict structure from values to keys

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, key-value-store

Lets say i have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'year': [2006, 2012, 2003, 2006, 2012, 2018, 2020, 2011, 2000, 2001, 2013, 2013]}
```

How can i create a new dictionary looking like this?

```
new_dict = {'1': '2006', '2': '2012', ..., '12': '2013'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(zip(my_dict['month'], my_dict['year']))
```

Converting to string values:

```
months = [str(item) for item in my_dict['month']]
years = [str(item) for item in my_dict['year']]
dict(zip(months, years))
```

Comment: if only a technicality, the OP seems to have asked for string as output, not int